# Extract specific text from a document

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a text file that I need to extract specific data elements from.

Example text:

```
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/example0.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-01-22</lastmod>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/example1.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-01-21</lastmod>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/example2.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-01-21</lastmod>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/example3.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-01-20</lastmod>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://example.com/example4.html</loc>
    <lastmod>2019-01-20</lastmod>
    <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
```

I want to extract:

```
https://example.com/example0.html
https://example.com/example1.html
https://example.com/example2.html
https://example.com/example3.html
https://example.com/example4.html
```

**Please keep in mind that the date is not static**

Comment: Please, don't cross post: https://superuser.com/q/1396862/763386

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an exact duplicate of https://superuser.com/q/1396862/763386

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace:

```
Find:    <url>\s+<loc>(.*?)<\/loc>\s+<lastmod>.*?<\/lastmod>\s+<priority>.*?<\/priority>\s+<\/url>
Replace: $1
```

The approach of this answer is to completely match every `<url>` tag, then replace with the URL captured in the pattern, leaving us just with the URLs you expect.

### Demo

Note: In general it is not desirable to use regex to parse HTML/XML content.  Rather, it is better to use a parser.  The above solution is given for Notepad++ which doesn't have a built in XML parser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to extract through notepad++ just do:

```
https?://[^<]+
```

Comment: it worked but am wondering how can I extract the urls after selecting them ?
PS: I did resolve the issue, I just want to know how this method works 
thank you